# Tabla de frecuencia con condiciones

Tags: r

Quiero una tabla de frecuencias de la distribución de hombres y mujeres por ciudad, restringiendo las observaciones a los que tienen entre 12 y 18 años de edad.

```
tab_1 <- table(data$city, data$sexo, data$edad >=12 & data$edad <=18)
tab_1`
```

Cuando visualizo lo que hice, salen 2 tablas una que antes de presentarla dice `FALSE`  y otra que dice `TRUE`. Solo me interesa la que dice `TRUE`, porque es la que cumple con la condición indicada, hay alguna forma de hacerlo?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Lo que ocurre es que tal como has planteado la solución, estás generando una tabla de frecuencias entre tres observaciones:

1. `data$city`
2. `data$sexo`
3. `data$edad >=12 & data$edad <=18` que en definitiva es un vector de lógicos

Lo que deberías hacer, es filtrar las observaciones en primer lugar, antes de invocar a `table()`, por ejemplo:

```
data_new <- data[data$edad >=12 & data$edad <=18,]
tab_1 <- table(data_new$city, dataa_new$sexo)
```

Answer (score 0):

Puedes intentar esto.

```
library(dplyr)

data %>%
  filter(edad >= 12, edad <= 18) %>%
  count(city, sexo)
```

Comment: Por favor explica cómo y por qué tú código funciona para lo que requiere OP, para que de esta manera otros programadores puedan aprovechar la pregunta y tu respuesta